# Does For..Next stops the loading Form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my form3 i have this code

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim vs As Integer

    Me.Label3.Text = Form1.Label59.Text
    Me.Label4.Text = Form1.Label61.Text
    Me.Label3.Text = Form1.Label59.Text
    vs = Form1.DataGridView2.Rows.Count
    Me.Dgv.Rows.Clear()
    If vs > 1 Then Dgv.Rows.Add(vs - 1)

    For ss = 0 To vs
        Me.Dgv.Rows(ss).Cells(0).Value = Form1.DataGridView2.Rows(ss).Cells(0).Value
        Me.Dgv.Rows(ss).Cells(1).Value = Form1.DataGridView2.Rows(ss).Cells(1).Value
        Me.Dgv.Rows(ss).Cells(2).Value = Form1.DataGridView2.Rows(ss).Cells(2).Value
        Me.Dgv.Rows(ss).Cells(3).Value = Form1.DataGridView2.Rows(ss).Cells(3).Value
    Next

    Me.Text = "123"

End Sub
```

it works properly at the end of "for .... next" but does not see anything i write after "for next". for example in this code my form3's text does not change to "123". i tried everything but it does not see anything after "for next" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable 'vs' contains a count, which you use in the for-loop to iterate over a zero-based indexed array.  Change the line to:

```
For ss = 0 To vs - 1
```

You should be receiving errors about this?  To confirm, before making the change I've suggested, consider placing a [Try...Catch Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) around the loop.

Comment: on first load of form3 it does not give error but on the second load of form3 it gives error. Thanks a lot.... you are right, i must put "vs -1" to prevent to try to add data more than row in dgv. It works properly now. Thank you a lot. If i have 15 reputation, i would vote up.:)

Comment: @Caravansary You're most welcome.  Always something to be on the watch for, Arrays/Collections use zero-based indexes so keep that in mind. ;-)